# 3D WebGL in Cordova on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, cordova, webgl

Is there a way to use WebGL in Cordova on mobile devices? If not, is there a mobile alternative?

I want support for ios, mainly because android crosswalk already supports webgl.

Comment: WebGL is based on OpenGL ES, which is designed with mobile devices in mind. I coded one webgl app and it worked on my old iphone.

Comment: I was talking about using a WebView for webgl, it doesn't work on webviews. (I am using intel xdk cordova)

Comment: I'm pretty sure CocoonJS supports WebGL on iOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes WebGL support on iOS8 and its WebView. so all Cordova/PhoneGap based App will work as well.

Good one: http://www.sencha.com/blog/apple-shows-love-for-html5-with-ios-8

and these as well: 
http://blog.ludei.com/webgl-ios-8-safari-webview/

http://toucharcade.com/2014/09/18/ios-8-webgl-demo-quake-iii/

Answer (score 2):

i'm using Crosswalk + Cordova and its looking good

[Crosswalk Project](https://crosswalk-project.org/)